# How to refactor this MySQL code?

Tags: mysql, refactoring

```
    SELECT AVG(`col5`)
    FROM `table1`
    WHERE `id` NOT IN (
        SELECT `id` FROM `table2`
        WHERE `col4` = 5
    )
    group by `col2` having sum(`col3`) > 0
UNION
    SELECT MAX(`col5`)
    FROM `table1`
    WHERE `id` NOT IN (
        SELECT `id` FROM `table2`
        WHERE `col4` = 5
    )
    group by `col2` having sum(`col3`) = 0
```

For readability and performance reasons, I think this code could be refactored. But how?

**EDITIONS**

1. removed the outer select
2. made the first select to return a sum and the second one to return another value
3. replaced the `SUM` by `AVG`

Comment: I'm confused because you have `GROUP BY`, but no aggregate columns in the `SELECT`. What columns are you returning?

Comment: @Marcus I corrected the example to reflect the real reason why there is a union

Comment: You don't need `UNION` anyway. Consider using `IF` function. See my answer below updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t2.col4 = 5
where t2.id is null
group by t1.col2 
having sum(col3) >= 0
```

The outer select is missing the `FROM` clause and was not adding anything so I removed it. The `NOT IN` is inefficient compared to the LEFT OUTER JOIN method so I replaced that. The two `UNION`s were easily combined into one by using `>=`.

**Update:**
Note the use of `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`. I don't *think* you want to remove duplicates, and it will perform faster this way.

```
SELECT AVG(t1.col5) 
FROM table1 t1 
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t2.col4 = 5 
where t2.id is null 
group by t1.col2  
having sum(t1.col3) > 0  
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(t1.col5) 
FROM table1 t1 
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t2.col4 = 5 
where t2.id is null 
group by t1.col2  
having sum(t1.col3) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions: I removed the outer select, I can use your `left outer join` suggestion, but I can't combine the `UNION` because the code is slightly different from what I wrote first. I rewrote the question to show why it is difficult to combine both statements.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I'll post the solution in a moment.

Comment: You're right, SUM and MAX don't mix well. The real operations I use are AVG and MAX. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Note I used `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`, for better performance; updated query to use `AVG`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t2.col4 <> 5 AND SUM(t1.col3) > 0 GROUP BY t1.col2
```

Comment: the real code is slightly different from what I wrote at first. I rewrote the question to show why it is difficult to combine both statements

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE col2 IN
(SELECT col2
    FROM `table1` 
    WHERE `id` NOT IN ( 
        SELECT `id` FROM `table2` 
        WHERE `col4` = 5 
    ) 
    group by `col2` having sum(`col3`) >= 0
)
```

When using `GROUP BY`, you should only return columns that are named in the `GROUP BY` clause or that include an aggregate function. Therefore, the inner `SELECT` here gets the col2 values where the sum is greater than or equal to zero, then the outer `SELECT` grabs the entire row for those values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    IF(SUM(`table1`.`col3`) > 0, AVG(`table1`.`col5`), MAX(`table1`.`col5`))
FROM `table1`
    LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`id` = `table1`.`id` AND `table2`.`col4` = 5
WHERE `table2`.`id` IS NULL
GROUP BY `table1`.`col2`
HAVING SUM(`table1`.`col3`) >= 0
```

Also `*` is considered harmful. If you want to make your query forward-compatible with possible future changes to your DB model, specify columns by their names.

Comment: the real code is slightly different from what I wrote at first. I rewrote the question to show why it is difficult to combine both statements